# vs code phpcs only works sometimes

Tags: visual-studio-code, linter, phpcs

Sometimes I open a php file in VS Code and no linting occurs until I open the linting console from the bottom, switch over to the terminal pane where a dialog shows up that asks me if I trust the authors of this workspace.  If I say yes then linting errors are shown until I close VS Code.

Other times, I open a php file in vs code, no linting errors show so I open the linting console from the bottom and switch over to the terminal pane but nothing happens.

There is no pattern that I can see as to when the linter will work and when it will do nothing.  I have never encountered a problem like this.  Does anyone know anything about this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sometimes the linter lints my code when I start VS Code and other times nothing happens with the linter when I start VS Code.  There is no error that I can see in any case.